# Paypal. Payment information page

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I use payment via paypal and I need the customer to enter secure payment information on my webpage.

After reading tutorials, I need to set action to paypal => "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" and the customer to complete their data on paypal website.

Is it possible to have customers enter card data on my own website? Can you  offer any advice or manuals on how to implement this?

Thanks. Sorry for my English

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I agree with @TRiG.  You don't wanna handle card information unless you absolutely have to; that's a big set of problems on its own.

Comment: @TRiG implementation according to design

Comment: @dev_feed Why? explain please or if you can give me some links. I'm a new guy in e-commerce

Comment: @user2115659 if you handle the purchases yourself, you'll be liable for taxes, licensing, and, in the event of an attack, you'd be liable if your customer information was stolen.

Comment: @user2115659 see [this link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/adding-paypal-to-your-web-site.html)

Comment: @user2115659 see also [PCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard)

Comment: @user2115659 you're welcome! just be careful in whatever you choose, it can be pretty rocky when you implement this yourself.

Comment: Here's [more information on why you probably don't want to do that](http://timothy.green.name/blog/2013/01/tentative-thoughts-on-payment-gateways/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have customers enter card data on my own website?

Yes it's possible.  Is it advisable? Not if you don't have to.

If you are passing the user to PayPal to complete payment, there is absolutely no reason for you to collect the CC data on your own website.  All you do is add to the customer's risk as well as your own (since there are certain legal ramifications if you screw something up).

If what you are asking is how can you do the entire process on your own site, then that's a different answer and a pretty involved one.  PayPal has [options for this with different plans](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/plans-and-pricing?intl_cid=Bizv1-1HP-CTA%7Cweb%3asee-plans-and-pricing) and each of those options has plenty of documentation on how to setup and configure the process.

Answer (score 1):

As @butlerblog mentioned, there are different levels of integration for ecommerce.  If you truly want to stay away from paypal but are considering your other options for third party integration, you can check [this site](http://www.findmyhosting.com/how-ecommerce-works/) to start getting an idea of how involved with ecommerce you want to get.